# Is it possible to use an apache-ignite rdd implementation in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, ignite

I am using apache spark to run some python data code via pyspark. I am running in Spark standalone mode with 7 nodes.

Is it possible to use the apache-ignite RDD implementation in this set up? Doe it offer any advantage?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use Ignite in any Spark deployment. Please refer to documentation to better understand possible advantages: https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/docs/ignite-for-spark

Comment: Can I access same IgniteRDD from different sessions created in different applications written in different languages (specifically java, scala and python)? (Asked [new question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49607472/is-it-possible-to-accesss-apache-ignite-rdd-from-different-spark-session-from-di))